# Please help me solve the below Directional coupler problem

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, electromagnetic, microwave, coupler

[image]

I have tried and my answer keep coming 0db.I am not sure this answer is right as this is only kind of problem I have seen where port is short circuited.

Comment: I  guess the directivity is asked and every branch of the coupler except the short is matched. Even with this simplification this is not solvable. There's no data how the phase angles of the waves from the short and from the source to the power meter fit.

Comment: @user287001 While I did assume the coupled ports on the directional coupler were matched, and yes that is needed to solve this. Once you make that assumption this is perfectly solvable. See my answer below.

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman excuse me, but there's no answer. Is it still under construction?

Comment: @user287001 Sorry check again.

Comment: @user287001 I did need to make an additional assumption though by the way. But typically I find questions always require the user to make certain assumptions. Usually if i find a question isnt solvable I ask myself what assumptions I'm not making that is implied.

Comment: That extra assumption can well be a general rule in questioner's studying material (=no explicit separate line  means components are joined together straight without intermediate lines). But the calculation with that extra assumption is ok.

Comment: @user287001 yea if this were a real world scenario he was measuring those assumptions would need to be explicit. But when we are talking about a theory question I think its a safe bet those assumptions are implied, particularly when we consider they are needed to get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three assumptions need to be made to solve this problem..

1. that the two coupled ports on the directional coupler are properly terminated.
2. the distance between the directional coupler and the far end of the transmission line where the short is at is electrically short, as in many orders of magnitude shorter than the wavelength being dealt with. Essentially the same as shorting the output port on the directional coupler directly.
3. That the directivity measured in dB is greater than the coupling also measured in dB. Keep in mind both these figures are the gain **from** coupled port **to** the transmission line. So a positive value implies the gain from transmission line to coupled port is the negative of this value. So by saying we assume the directivity is larger than the coupling this means we assume there is greater attenuation from reflected to forward coupled port then from forward to forward coupled port. This final assumption is pretty much always the case so its a safe one to make in any situation.

Taking these as assumptions then we can solve the problem. The input power is 0.01W, lets convert this to dBm to make it easier.

$$
  \begin{align}
  P_{dBm} & = 10 \cdot log\left( 1000 \cdot \frac{P_W}{1W}\right) \tag{1} \\\\
  P & = 10 \cdot log\left( 1000 \cdot \frac{0.01W}{1W}\right) \tag{2} \\\\
  P & = 10\ dBm \tag{3}
  \end{align}
$$

Since we know the coupling is 20 dB then we know that the power seen at the forward coupled port would be \$-10\ dBm\$ if we had perfect directivity. Because we are working in dBm it is simple subtraction.

$$
  \begin{align}
  P_f & = 10\ dBm - 20\ dB \tag{4} \\\\
  P_f & = -10\ dBm \tag{5}
  \end{align}
$$

Now lets calculate the actual power see see at the forward port in dBm.

$$
  \begin{align}
  P_\hat{f} & = 10 \cdot log\left( 1000 \cdot \frac{0.00000001W}{1W}\right) \tag{6} \\\\
  P_\hat{f} & = -50\ dBm \tag{7}
  \end{align}
$$

this means the forward couple's port power without directivity effects in plain numbers is:

$$
  P_f = -10\ dBm = 0.0001\ W \tag{8}
$$

and for the power once directivity effects are applied as it leaks in from reflected we already know is.

$$
  P_\hat{f} = -50\ dBm = 0.00000001\ W \tag{9}
$$

Since we need to subtract and add and we cant do that via power linearly lets convert this into volts.

$$
  \begin{align}
  P & = \frac{v^2}{R} \tag{10} \\\\
  V & = \sqrt{P \cdot R} \tag{11}
  \end{align}
$$

Now we know the forward signal without directivity, minus the signal leaked in due to directivity, must equal the signal we actually see. Therefore.

$$
  \sqrt{P_f \cdot Z_0} - V_D = \sqrt{P_\hat{f} \cdot Z_0} \tag{12}
$$

Note the only reason we are subtracting here is because we know the reverse signal is 180 degrees out of phase with the forward, so it has a subtractive effect.

$$
  \begin{align}
  -V_D & = \sqrt{P_\hat{f} \cdot Z_0} + -\sqrt{P_f \cdot Z_0} \tag{13} \\\\
  V_D & = -\sqrt{P_\hat{f} \cdot Z_0} + \sqrt{P_f \cdot Z_0} \tag{14}
  \end{align}
$$

Then convert voltage back to power.

$$
  \begin{align}
  P_D & = \frac{V_D^2}{Z_0} \tag{15} \\\\
  P_D & = \frac{\left(-\sqrt{P_\hat{f} \cdot Z_0} + \sqrt{P_f \cdot Z_0}\right)^2}{Z_0} \tag{16}
  \end{align}
$$

Since we can assume all positive values here this simplifies to:

$$
  P_D = -2 \cdot \sqrt{P_f \cdot P_\hat{f}} + P_\hat{f} + P_f \tag{17}
$$

Plugin in our values and find the actual value:

$$
  P_D = 0.00009801\ W = -10.087296108\ dBm \tag{18}
$$

Now we know reflected wave in the transmission line is \$10\ dBm\$ and we know the actual power of reflected wave in the forward port due to directivity, so by simple subtraction we can arrive at the directivity in dB, remember dBm minus dBm equals dB.

$$
  \begin{align}
  10\ dBm - P_D & = D \tag{19} \\\\
  D & = 10\ dBm - (-10.087296108\ dBm) \tag{20} \\\\
  D & = 20.087296108\ dB \tag{21}
  \end{align}
$$

Comment: But the answer given is 40db .

Comment: @SUNITAGUPTA Either the answer given is wrong or I screwed up somewhere. I'll see if i can find in error in what I stated and let you know if i correct it.

Comment: I got a similar answer but instead of going through Voltages I simply subtracted power due to short .But the answer in the book is given 40db.

Comment: @SUNITAGUPTA You can't simply subtract power because of its non-linear relationship to voltage. The voltages are the things that actually subtract and since power is non-linear to it then subtracting power isn't equivelant.

Comment: Ok I'll try with voltages.

Comment: @SUNITAGUPTA I fixed the answer. My mistake before was that I thought directivity was the amount that leaks from reflected coupled port to forward coupled port. It is in fact the amount that leaks from reflected mainline to forward coupled port. I also made the math much easier by using dBm instead of plain values.

Comment: Pardon to say, but I didn't get what reflected mainline port means. According to the definition I know directivity is ratio of forward port power and backward port power when input is applied to only one port. Also I didn't understand why ratio of forward port power and actual measured power should be directivity. I mean actual measured voltage should be equal to forward voltage due to input source - backward voltage due to reflected port.

Comment: And as we have measured power we can take measured voltages square (considering Zo=1, as ultimately it is going be cancelled).

Comment: Thanks for being thoughtful enough to make it easier, but I am much more comfortable in ratios them dBm. I am still confused why earlier answer was wrong, and this one is correct.

Comment: Directivity is how much of the forward power leaks to the reflected coupled port, that is correct.. but when there is reflected power it is similarly the amount of power leaked from the reflected wave into the forward port. It works both ways.

Comment: And yes if you wish you can of course convert the dBm measurements into voltages and then back again, it just makes the math harder, but you can certainly to that. Just do the substitution in the math and you are good to go.

Comment: But sir measured power will be due to forward coupled signal of input and (in reverse phase) backward reflected power if we consider short circuit power as input power.

Comment: Here what you have given in answer is measured power (.01microW) is simply backward reflected power (or isolation factor * Power reflected at short circuit) considering short circuit as input.

Comment: @SUNITAGUPTA sorry not sure what your trying to say here.The forward signal goes to the forward coupled port through the normal coupling value. Some of that will leak to the reverse coupled port through the directivity value but we can ignore that since we dont care about the output on the reverse coupled port. Similarly any reverse signal will also leak through to the forward port determined by the directivity value. Since the reverse signal is 180 degrees out of phase with the forward it will be subtractive. Thus the result we have here.

Comment: @SUNITAGUPTA typically the model that describes directivity assumes there is no reflected power and as such only talks about the forward power leaking into the reflected coupled port. But you have to understand this directivity applies in both direction and when there is a reflected signal i leaks in the other direction as well.

Comment: @ Jeffrey Phillips Freeman Sir sorry to trouble you again but according to new answer directivity =forward power assuming no reflection from short / measured power.Now by your words measured power =  forward power assuming no reflection from short - backward power (due to imperfect isolation between short circuit and power meter),but the formula of directivity should be forward power assuming no reflection from short /backward power assuming no reflection from short(or port 3 power).The point in the question was to find backward power and substitute in formulae to get directivity isn't it sir.

Comment: To calculate backward power we would  have to use symmetry property of directional coupler so that the portion of power of reflected wave which appeared at the port with power meter (backward power with respect to short circuit port) is equal to backwakward power assuming no reflection from short.Measured power (.01microW) is due to forward power (.1mW) and backwarf power. As we find backward power and divide it by .1mW ,it should give directivity.Am I wrong sir

Comment: That is exactly what I did with my math. We already know backwards power is equal to forward power. I used that assumption, and the measured power ont he forward port in order to calculate the directivity. What you specify is exactly what I did, you are misunderstanding something apparently but I am not sure what. If you wish to continue this please move the conversation to chat and I will continue it there, the comments are getting too long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113256/discussion-between-sunita-gupta-and-jeffrey-phillips-freeman).

Comment: @tim Thanks for the edit, i wasnt aware that it would number the equations by using that format. I will certainly use that format in the future. Thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score -1):

The input power is 10 mW, or +10 dBm.
The measured power is 0.01 uW, or -50 dBm
That's an attenuation of 60 dB from source to sensor.

If the book says that directivity of the coupler is 40 dB, then we can arrive at the signal loss by looking around to find numbers that add up. Adding the coupler loss, and the directivity, we get 60 dB.

That means the block labelled 'short' has to be a perfect load, to be returning no power.

Note that if the load was anything other than a perfect load, we would have to know what the electrical length was between coupler and load, as the signal going to the sensor is the vector sum of the coupled+phase shifted reverse power, and the coupled+directivity forward power in the coupler. Without that knowledge, it's not possible to answer the question.

Comment: Since the question is intended to be answerable I think its a safe bet that we can assume we are dealing with ideals here. That is the short is perfect and reflects 100% of the power. I think it can also be assumed that the distance between the directional coupler and the short is infentesimal.